# Switch spell-checker of Chrome to a different language?

Tags: chrome-for-android, spell-check

On my smartphone I normally use German as default language.

Sometimes (like when posting here) I would like to use a different language for its spell-checker.

How do I accomplish this?

Note that I do already switch the keyboard from German to English spell-checking (so I get English completion), but Chrome will still underline every English word as "wrong".